# The importance of RDLENGTH in resource record

Tags: dns

The RRs have a level format: NAME - TYPE - CLASS- TTL - RDLENGTH - RDATA.

Whats the purpose of RDLENGTH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As defined in RFC 1035 §3.2.1:

> RDLENGTH
> an unsigned 16 bit integer that specifies the length in
> octets of the RDATA field.

The RDATA field is of variable size. It is fixed in size for some records like `A` or `AAAA` but can be "any" size for records like `TXT`.

So when you receive a DNS packet you need to know the size of the `RDATA` part (to allocate buffers, to know where the next record starts, etc.). So you read the 16 bit integer of the RDLENTH and then you know how many octets following this position are indeed the RDATA part.

Don't attempt to write any low level DNS code without having read RFC 1034 and 1035 thoroughly multiple times. Pay special attention to "name compression" and the notion of "resource records sets".